# Parallel Task Como melhorar o Desempenho dessa função

Tags: sql, vb.net, servidor, task

Eu gostaria de uma sugestão para melhorar o desempenho desse métodos. Eles tem demorado demais para concluir.
Por favor se a pergunta não estiver muito clara só falar que eu tento melhorar vou disponibilizar umas imagens com os codigos.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Bom aqui basicamente é o laço faço algumas verificações e transfiro para o tratamento adequado[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Aqui é o update que estou realizando [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Aqui é  método que instancia a classe que chama o dao para não haver bloqueio por algum recurso
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Editei 23/09- Aqui eu precisei limitar as tasks simultaneas pois recebia exception se deixar sem o paralleloption

Comment: Rodrigo, evite colocar imagens com o código, prefira sempre escrever o código diretamente na pergunta. Quanto ao seu problema, é capaz que não seja um problema com as tarefas paralelas. Você já executou essa rotina de forma normal, sem `Task`, para ver se demora também? Já testou essa query diretamente no SQL Server para ver qual o desempenho dela?

Comment: Olá tudo bem obrigado por responder, bom sim já testei essa query no banco cerca 2 segundos já tratei os possíveis erros, e quanto ao código sim houve uma melhora no desempenho com as tasks mais ainda é lento.